# HttpWebRequest.UserAgent is set, but not working in response

Tags: c#, silverlight, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-7.1

I'm developing an App for Windows Phone 7.1.1

I'm using `HttpWebRequest` to get HTML code of a website
The problem is, it's alsway get the "Desktop" version of HTML code
After google, I find out it's controlled by UserAgent string

So, I set the `UserAgent` of `HttpWebRequest`

But it's still not get the "Mobile" version of HTML code

here is my code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(link, UriKind.Absolute));
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0)";
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseReady), request);
```

This is code for ResponseReady

```
private void ResponseReady(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = asyncResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

blah blah blah
```

The Response is always the same as not UserAgent at all (Desktop version)

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "The Response is always the same as not UserAgent at all (Desktop version)"? The sentence doesn't make sense. You may also find that the version of the site served depends on more than the user agent. It's up to the individual web site, and you haven't given any indication of that...

Comment: Are you sure the server is setup to return a mobile version for that UserAgent?

Comment: What web site are you trying to read information from? Knowing that we can see how it responds when we test it.

Comment: The result string is the same as request.UserAgent is not set (comment out that line of code)
The website is an adult website, so maybe i cannot post it here. But i tried with Google Chrome (with User-Agent Switcher Extension, paste the same UserAgent string to it) and site return the same as I use my Windows Phone to browse it.

Comment: Some site use m.blahblahblah.com for mobile version, some site use blahblahblah.com/mobile for mobile version.
This is not that cenarios. The site use the same address for both. Browse on desktop and on mobile give me different layouts, links, and everything else

Comment: Try to do it manualy - request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Your user agent string"); If it doesn't work, create localhost (php is fastest for test) script, which can show you user-agent string passed.
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problems is solved

Just use WebViewer / WebBrowser control to load the link. Then use OuterHtml to get the HTML Code of that website. Really simple.
You can set visibility of that control to Colapse to hide it on the screen